# Website Navigation Menu loading incorrect for mobile

Tags: php, html, jquery, css, wordpress

Our website is reporting CLS problems through PageSpeed Insights for the Mobile platform due to an issue with our responsive menu.

Upon first loading the homepage, the desktop menu appears for a fraction of a second and then gets replaced by our hamburger icon for the mobile-friendly menu, causing the rest of the content to shift upward.

[mobile menu loads desktop menu before replacing it with mobile menu](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Jc8zM.jpg)

As you can see, initial load shows the desktop menu, but then it fixes itself in less than a second to this and adjusts header size (causing CLS issues):

[menu after the desktop menu has been replaced with the mobile menu](https://i.stack.imgur.com/67K6y.jpg)

I have all media and screen-size related CSS changes in my Stylesheet, but the stylesheet is rather long and the media related changes are near the end of the stylesheet. My web page is loading content before the CSS can determine which to display and which to hide, causing CLS shifting.

When looking at functions.php, we have a large function that enqueues scripts and then styles. We have it enqueueing jquery, followed by a custom.js file, and then the menu. I was going to try pulling the menu enqueue out of the function to get it to load separately and at the top of functions.php in hopes to get it to load and make the correct menu choice before loading the header on the page so that the page is not suffering from CLS problems.

Can I get my website to choose the correct CSS menu choice before loading in the header? I apologize for any lack of knowledge as I am trying to learn how to optimize my website for PageSpeed Insight and I had basic HTML/CSS experience that needs fleshing out for optimization experience.

I use WordPress to host if that helps.

Thank you in advance!

I tried using !important tags in CSS for displaying the hamburger icon faster and tried pulling out my menu from my functions.php function that seems like too much is loading together, but the enqueue of my menu is calling for jquery, making this difficult because the large function calls jquery first:

wp_enqueue_script('menu', get_stylesheet_directory_uri().'/menu.js', array('jquery'), array());

Comment: It sounds like it might be "mobile first" issue, in that you don't have your CSS written for mobiles first, and only override with media queries for larger screens. Can you confirm that? Please post the completely reduced example with only HTML/CSS related to you problem and create a snippet in your question: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-create-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.